# correct pattern of Ktor's HttpClient usage

Tags: kotlin, ktor

What's the correct pattern of usage for HttpClient in KTOR. Should I use it like singleton per app lifecycle, or should I create it per each request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that you may have more than one client per app if you need to connect to more than one logical services.
But if you are dealing with one single HTTP server it's better to have one client because it establishes and holds a connection with server. It also allocates the following resources: prepared threads, coroutines and connections. If you have multiple clients you can potentially run out of these resources.

Comment: Lately the documentation also contains this remark: "Note that creating HttpClient is not a cheap operation, and it's better to reuse its instance in the case of multiple requests." (https://ktor.io/docs/create-client.html#close-client)

Answer (score 4):

> Should I use it like singleton per app lifecycle, or should I create it per each request

Creation of a http client instance is usually a bit resource intensive, hence you should not create an instance of client for every request. You should create just **one http client instance per app's lifecycle**, injected wherever required in your app, ensuring that

- you have used the right http client configurations like the thread pool size, timeouts etc
- you are [releasing](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/quick-start/client.html#releasing-resources) the resources upon the app's shutdown.

The client can be configured with `HttpClientEngineConfig`([doc](https://api.ktor.io/1.3.2/io.ktor.client.engine/-http-client-engine-config/index.html)) or any of its inheritors. More details in the documentation [here](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/quick-start/client.html).

Answer (score 3):

It is better to reuse the `HttpClient` instance for performance reasons if the requests can be performed using the same configuration/settings.

But in some cases you have to create separate instances because the features of a `HttpClient` are determined by the [engine](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html) and the [plugins](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-plugins.html) specified when [creating](https://ktor.io/docs/create-client.html) the instance.
For example when using [bearer authentication](https://ktor.io/docs/bearer-client.html) the `HttpClient` instances can be reused only when sending requests to the same resource server (with the same authorization configuration).
Similarly, if two requests should use different [timeouts](https://ktor.io/docs/timeout.html#configure_plugin) then they can be performed only by different `HttpClient`s.

To summarize, a `HttpClient` instance should be created per "feature set", determined by the required engine and plugins. 
A new `HttpClient` instance can be created easily by using the `HttpClient.config { ... }` method, which allows to customize an existing client, while sharing the underlying client engine.